# How to change Column Type with db-migrate in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, liquibase

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and the [db-migrate](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) plugin 1.3.5. My database is mysql.

The existing model which is in sync with the database is:

```
 class User {
    String description
 }
```

Hibernate makes a varchar(255) in mysql out of it. I need a longer text column so I made:

```
 class User {
    String description

static mapping = {
    description type: 'text'
}
 }
```

Then I ran dbm-gorm-diff change-column.groovy -add

And got the following error. What should I do?

```
| Starting dbm-gorm-diff
| Error org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 7
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GormDiff.areEquivalent(GormDiff.groovy:146)
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GormDiff.isDifferent(GormDiff.groovy:114)
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GormDiff.compare(GormDiff.groovy:68)
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.createAndPrintFixedDiff(ScriptUtils.groovy:244)
| Error     at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(DbmGormDiff:53)
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:132)
| Error     at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmGormDiff:50)
| Error     at grails.plugin.databasemigration.ScriptUtils.executeAndWrite(ScriptUtils.groovy:104)
| Error     at DbmGormDiff$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmGormDiff:49)
```

Comment: Might be a bug in the plugin

Comment: @JamesKleeh do you know any work around?

Comment: You could use `sqlType`, but you are database specific at that point.

Comment: Can you post an answer for that? since I only use mysql this might not be a problem.

Comment: I was facing similar issue. This might help: [Issue with dbm version 1.3.3](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-120). Upgrading to 1.3.8 helped!

Answer (score 0):

As `@raxith` commented, upgrading `dbm` from to `1.3.2` to `1.3.8` using `grails 2.2.5` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You can change it to `sqlType` to get your `dbm-gorm-diff` to run. Then change it back afterwards. There are a couple JIRA issues in relation to this type of error for the plugin.

Comment: you mean like this: static mapping = {
    description sqlType: 'text'
}

Comment: Could you elaborate please